# How to uninstall Trac on Windows?

Tags: windows, uninstallation, trac

I installed Trac on Windows 7 using `Trac-1.0.1.win32.exe`.

How do I cleanly uninstall this? My reason for uninstalling is that I installed it with Python 3.4, and then discovered that it actually requires Python 2.7. So I would like to remove the existing install, and re-install it for Python 2.7 .

Nothing appears for Trac in the Windows 7 "Add/Remove Programs" area. There is a program `RemoveTrac.exe` that was created under the `Python34` directory, however when I run that it pops up a MessageBox with title `Runtime Error` and text `This program is normally started by windows`, and it does not uninstall.

Comment: Where does Trac-1.0.1.win32.exe come from?

Comment: From http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDownload  . Originally I tried `Trac-1.0.1.zip` from the same location, however it didn't contain `tracd.exe` (so I'm not quite sure what that zipfile is supposed to be).

Comment: hmm... On Windows, I'd prefer to install Bitnami Trac Stack, an all-in-one package of Apache+Trac+Svn+Python running out of the box and saving lots of install hell hours.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but to me it seems that installer just checks your environment, detects some pathes and sets them in the installed Trac environment. Trac should be on top of Python and SVN. So likely, you can just remove the installed Trac directory.

Comment: It looks like the installer code is here: http://svn.edgewall.org/repos/trac/sandbox/installer/trac/